# Making pip work in Pycharm with Cygwin Python 3.4.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, pip, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2016.3 and have pointed the python interpreter at the one I have installed using Cygwin

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\python3.4m.exe
```

This works fine and runs my code sucessfully with the various packages that I have installed using pip.

However, all the imports are underlined in red wit the "no module installed error" and if I try to upgrade a package through PyCharm I get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/C:\\Users\\{USERNAME}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging'
```

Where `{USERNAME}` is my username.

Comment: Your Pycharm is set up with a default unix directory of /usr/bin but you are on Windows.  I don't have a version in front of my, but I would guess it is somewhere in the settings.  Try to find it and remove it.

Comment: I assume that the /usr/bin is coming from python maybe not a setting in Pycharm?

Comment: However, all the imports are underlined in red wit the "no module installed error" and if I try to upgrade a package through PyCharm <----- Leads me to believe it is in Pycharm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Cygwin Python installs site-packages in the unix way at

```
c:\cygwin64\lib\python3.4\site-packages
```

Something in PyCharm knows this because it does find them to put them in the list of libraries but it does note find them to add them to the modules it checks for 'no module found purposes'.

If you add the above folder to the Interpreter Paths. Accessed by clicking the button with no name described at https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiI33.jpg then it will suddenly start working.

Hat tip to reddit page https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/42n7u6/pycharm_not_detecting_modules_possible_pip_issue/